# Creating a test XMPP client for testing

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, xmppframework

Im trying to create an XMPP test client in Java, I want to plug into my code that will behave like  real xmpp client but will output messages say for example to a log. Im aiming to do this as i want to test in a realistic setting or close to.

Ideally I dont want to mock or stub it, as i want an xmpp client running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have you come across [Psi](http://psi-im.org/)? It's a very powerful cross-platform XMPP client that lets you view the raw XMPP stream in its console as well as paste in your own XML to send directly. It may save you the time it would take to write your own Smack-based XMPP client. Also have a look at [gajim](http://gajim.org/) which I hear is similar.

Comment: thanks i also began loking at tigase, to created an embedded xmpp sevrer in my app.. am working on trying to run it as im finding it very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

this will help u send a message to a reciever on xmpp.
remember u will have to configure openfire before you run this

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

public class SenderTest 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
        //connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
     ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
     //ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
       XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            connection.login("sender@example.com", "a");
            System.out.println("Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);

        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to log in as " + connection.getUser());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    ChatManager chatmanager = connection.getChatManager();
    Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("receiver@gmail.com", new MessageListener() {
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            System.out.println("Received message: " + message);
        }
    });

    try {
        newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
        System.out.println("Message Sent...");
    }
    catch (XMPPException e) {
        System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
    }
}

}
```